# Survey data statistics

Tags: r, statistical-significance

I've made a survey where the users answer what their occupation is and what their hobbies are.

The list of job fields are the following:

```
1. System developer

2. Transport

3. Paramedic

4. Agriculture

5. Educaiton

6. Restaurants

7. Banks
```

Hobbies:

```
1. Computer games

2. Sport

3. Theatres/Movies

4. Dancing

5. Going to coffee shops/restaurants

6. Classical concerts

7. Rock concerts

8. Art exhibitions

9. Libraries
```

And now that we've had participants in our survey, we'd like to see if there is a significance between the two, on a significance level of 1% (not 5%). How could we achieve this?

So far we've tried the Welch's two sample t-test.

Code:

```
data = read.delim("survey.txt")
t.test(data$job, data$hobby)
```

and it gives me the answer:

```
data:  data$job and data$hobby
t = -16.304, df = 6309.9, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.0515249 -0.8258052
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 4.009321  4.947986
```

Is this correct?
So the p-value is only 0.00000000000000022.

And since our significance level is 1%...
0.00000000000000022 is less than 0.01.
Does that mean **it is significant**?

Here is the `survey.txt` (1000 lines, can't post it on stack here, so im linking it to pastebin instead): http://pastebin.com/raw/3JKGvPHn

Edit: I have now made a chi-square test like this:

```
tbl = table(data$job, data$hobby)
chisq.test(tbl)
```

And the output was:

```
Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  tbl
X-squared = 279.88, df = 48, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

It's still the same p-value. Is this correct?

Comment: Have you tried using Chi-square?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have two nominal categorical variables. So you shouldn't treat them like ordinal and take the averages. Can you do a chi-square test of independence?

**EDIT:**

Do you know how to reject a null hypothesis? You may want to get yourself a statistics text book. If you don't care, look at the p-value. It's very small so you can conclude your samples are significantly different on the two variables you give.

Comment: So the best way is to use a chi-square test? Could you post some code examples, I've never made it. And is there a specific way of doing it when it's 1% significance level, as opposed to 5%?

Comment: @TibiaRook I'm not saying it's the best. I'd argue it in my answer. Somebody else might come later and say I'm wrong. R-code for chi-square is easy on Google.

Comment: I did a chi-square test now and it gave the same p-value: Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  tbl
X-squared = 279.88, df = 48, p-value < 2.2e-16

Comment: @TibiaRook Please edit your question for the new data.

Comment: The new data? What do you mean?

Comment: @TibiaRook Please edit you question for the chi-square test results.

Comment: @Underminer I edited